# How to change default System font for xib?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uifont

I've swizzled systemFontOfSize:, boldSystemFontOfSize:, and systemFontOfSize:weight: but when I set the font to "System" in a xib it still sets it to the default value. How can I change the default "System" font for xibs?

I know I swizzled these methods properly because when they are called programmatically it works as expected.

I'm not interested in a solution related to setting label appearance because I need to be able to change the font size.

Comment: You can't change it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

In my suggest， you can also swizzled initWithCoder: for UILalbel ,UIButton ,UITextField. And modify the font according to your need in the swizzling method.